# CakePHP 4 custom plugin dont find classes

Tags: php, cakephp

I try to create a Custom Plugin for CakePHP 4. But everytime i become a error that the plugin cant find the classes of the plugin.

I load the plugin in the Application.php

```
use Wirecore\CakePHP_JWT\Plugin as CakePHPJwt;

$plugin = new CakePHPJwt();
$this->addPlugin($plugin);
```

In the composer.json file of cake its also loaded:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "Wirecore\\CakePHP_JWT\\": "./plugins/CakePHP-JWT-Plugin/src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Test\\": "tests/",
        "Cake\\Test\\": "vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests/",
        "Wirecore\\CakePHP_JWT\\Test\\": "./plugins/CakePHP-JWT-Plugin/tests/"
    }
}
```

and i create a file in /plugins/CakePHP-JWT-Plugin/src/Middleware/JwtMiddleware.php with example code of the documentation [Middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/middleware.html#creating-middleware). I changed the namespace of the example code to

```
namespace Wirecore\CakePHP_JWT\Middleware;
```

after this i try to load the middle in the middleware function of the plugin but everytime i become this error:

> Class 'Wirecore\CakePHP_JWT\Middleware\TrackingCookieMiddleware' not found

here the code of the middleware function:

```
use Wirecore\CakePHP_JWT\Middleware\TrackingCookieMiddleware;

$middlewareQueue->add(new TrackingCookieMiddleware());
return $middlewareQueue;
```

i have tried to change the namespace but it does not work, and i try it with composer dumpautoload but again it changed nothing. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autoload section in the composer file is what tells PHP how to find your namespaces on disk. Your namespace prefix for the class, `Wirecore\CakePHP_JWT`, is not the namespace you listed in the `autoload` section, you listed `Wirecore\CakePHP-JWT-Plugin`. Either fix the namespace declaration to match autoload, like so:

```
use Wirecore\CakePHP-JWT-Plugin\ .. etc
```

.. or change fix the autoload section to match the name listed in your namespace declaration:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Wirecore\\CakePHP_JWT\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Wirecore\\CakePHP_JWT\\Test\\": "tests/",
        "Cake\\Test\\": "vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests/"
    }
}
```

Also, I'm not positive what standards your following here, but they potentially don't look right.

Is this a standalone plugin? If so, I'd mirror the structure from another standalone plugin like https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-geo/

If this *isn't* a standalone plugin (which is what seems more probable), but just a custom plugin being put directly into an existing CakePHP app, you're classes should be stuck in `/plugins` not `/src`, per the docs https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/plugins.html#creating-your-own-plugins

You might want to just use the [Bake utility](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/plugins.html#creating-a-plugin-using-bake) as a starting point (that'll solve your autoload issues too!) and copy your code into the classes it creates instead.

Comment: sry i post the wrong composer.json. the posted composer json was in the plugin
now i edit it to the composer.json of cakephp

Comment: What's the file path for the class it cant find then?

Comment: in the class /var/www/managerpanel-usermanagement/plugins/CakePHP-JWT-Plugin/src/Plugin.php it cannot found the class 'Wirecore\CakePHP_JWT\Middleware\TrackingCookieMiddleware'

Comment: I meant for the class it cant find - TrackingCookieMiddleware, its path will need to be a perfect case sensitive match to the namespace definition rile path, plus the other namespace parts - so `plugins/CakePHP-JWT-Plugin/src/Middleware/TrackingCookieMiddleware.php`